# Checkbox list with images

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, listbox

I made this windows phone user control:

[image]

**XAML:**

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Height="75" Width="353">
        <Image Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="img" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" />
        <TextBlock Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="77,12,0,0" Name="txt" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="215" FontSize="32" />
        <CheckBox Content="CheckBox" Height="68" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,3,10,0" Name="cb" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" />
</Grid>
```

And I call it like that in one of my pages

XAML.CS:

```
myListBox mls = new myListBox();
String[,] ls = { { "Text1", "/image/image1.png" }, { "Tex2", "/image/image2.png" } };
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
        mls.txt.Text = ls[i, 0];
        mls.img.Source = url(ls[i, 1]);
}

public ImageSource url (string path)
{
        Uri uri = new Uri(path, UriKind.Absolute);
        ImageSource imgSource = new BitmapImage(uri);
        return imgSource;
}
```

My problems are:

1) If I run this like that it take to the code below but if i change **for loop** to `i<1` it working fine (but not exactly what i expect look problem 2)

```
// Code to execute on Unhandled Exceptions
    private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            // An unhandled exception has occurred; break into the debugger
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        }
    }
```

2) With this code I set text and image but it not placing the image, only the text.

Comment: @weberc2 if you're going to edit the title please make it better don't just remove the tags

Comment: I just figured out the first problem... I needed to put `myListBox mls = new myListBox();` inside the loop.. Now my only problem is the second part..

Comment: @ConradFrix This was commonplace on the questions I've asked in the past--I'm continuing the tradition. Please direct me to a post showing some ruling on the matter and I'll happily change. For now, I'm doing what the community appears to want.

Comment: @weberc2 hmm well here's [the faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/148672) on writing good titles.  And there's been a couple discussion about this issue but these were before suggested edits. [I've opened a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158228/148672) regarding this.

Comment: @ConradFrix I'm following along with the meta. Thanks for the links! :)

Comment: Have you checked the log on the debugger? I think it may have something to do with the URI construction, have you tried to changing the uri kind to UriKind.Relative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar working code and I have used **UriKind** as **'Relative**' and not **'Absolute'**.

And one more thing. Make sure the **'Build Action'** under the properties of the image which you're using is set to **'Content' and NOT 'Resource'** or anything else.

Hopefully it'll work.